# What method should I use in Boto3 to create an entry in DynamoDB using AWS API gateway as a proxy service?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am new to coding. I appreciate the help.
I already create a DynamoDB table, API Gateway, child resource, child method(POST), integration type: AWS service proxy. I also created an IAM role to allow access to DynamoDB putitem.
I tried to add something to the table with postman and it worked well. However, now I want to add an item to the table with boto3 and I'm finding it hard to identify the method that I should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dydbsr = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
dbtable = 'myTable'
table = dydbsr.Table(dbtable)
```

If you have a partition key only:

```
partion key is: mypartitionkey

json_dictionary = {"mypartitionkey": "myvalue"}
table.put_item(Item=json_dictionary)
```

If you have a partition key and sort key. If sort key is defined it **MUST** be included

```
partion key is: mypartitionkey
sort key is: mysortkey

json_dictionary = {"mypartitionkey": "myvalue", "mysortkey": "myothervalue"}
table.put_item(Item=json_dictionary)
```

After adding partition and sort keys, then your attributes are just key:value pairs in the same json dictionary

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html) for examples to create, read, update, and delete an item with Python.

Comment: Thank you dossani. I appreciate your response.